# Display brightness adjustment not working

Tags: laptop, display

I have Ubuntu 11.04 installed on a Lenovo Thinkpad T410 laptop with nVidia GT218 display controller.  I am unable to adjust the display brightness.  Pressing Fn-Home and Fn-End brings up the display brightness on-screen display and the indicated level increases or decreases as it should.  But the actual display brightness does not change.

Earlier I was able to Ctrl-Alt-F1 over to a text terminal and then do Fn-Home / Fn-End to successfully change the display brightness, and then Ctrl-Alt-F8 back to the Gnome session with the new brightness.  But after upgrading to 11.04 the psuedoterminals have disappeared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have Thinkpad W510 and followed the instruction in [this page](http://ubuntuguide.net/change-screen-brightness-with-fn-key-in-ubuntu-11-0410-10).
It solved the problem that you describe and Fn+Home/End are now toggling the brightness of the screen.
I hope it will work for you too.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.

Comment: Ah, it did work!  It needed a reboot and not just restarting the X server.  In case that link goes away, the solution is to add a line saying `Option “RegistryDwords” “EnableBrightnessControl=1″` to the `Device` section of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Comment: This change in the xorg.conf made it work for me!